# Call a function from addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, function, audio, addeventlistener

I have the next code and I can't call ShowMedalMessage() function

```
var totalsounds = 3;
var currentsound = 1;
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'notify.wav');
audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    if (currentsound < totalsounds) {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
        currentsound = currentsound + 1;
    }
    ShowMedalMessage(1);
}, false);​
```

If the call to the function is before to audioElement.addEventListener, it calls properly, but if the line ShowMedalMessage(1); is inside, it doesn't work :(

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked console logs in chrome/firefox for errors? I dont see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: it might not be initiated at the time the event fires, does it logs some error?

Comment: I looking that in Firefox is not working the audio playing... with or without the ShowMedalMessage()... weird :/

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined file.php:132
ShowMedalMessage file.php:132
(anonymous function)

Comment: is  ShowMedalMessage globally defined ? which line is 132?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me in chrome and in firefox.

Hese is the live [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/q06iei?p=preview)

```
function showMessage() {
  document.write("Sound played");
}

var totalsounds = 3;
var currentsound = 1;
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/bugsbunny1.wav');
audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    if (currentsound < totalsounds) {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
        currentsound = currentsound + 1;
    }
    showMessage();
}, false);

document.body.appendChild(audioElement);
```

Comment: not working in firefox.. and I don't know why, I can't access to ShowMedalMessage from other function... weird.

Comment: Did the live example work for you ? If it did not work in firefox try updating the browser I guess.

Comment: your example is working, but not mine in firefox http://bit.ly/U2YrdM and as you can see, the function is not called in any browser

Comment: You should really fix your javascript errors in your local files maybe after that the script will work. You have one at line 512 in general_scripts.js 'document.mn_search is undefined'