# Calling a function from addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a form and I am adding an `addEventListener()` to the form. I wanted to call a function from within the `addEventListener()` but I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError` at the function call.

Code 1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function uploadFile(){
      alert("comes here");
  }

  uploadForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      var uploadFile = document.getElementById('upload-file').files;
      e.preventDefault();
      uploadFile();
  });
});
```

But if I change the above code to

Code 2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var test = function uploadFile(){
      alert("comes here");
  }

  uploadForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      var uploadFile = document.getElementById('upload-file').files;
      e.preventDefault();
      test();
  });
});
```

It works. I want to know why. It maybe something associated with the scope. But from whatever I know, I think the function(`uploadFile()`) and the function reference(`test`) has the same scope.

I am a self taught programmer so I don't know what to google to understand why this happens. The closest I got is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611812/call-a-function-from-addeventlistener) , [function naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

As an answer, I am just looking for some terms which I can google to understand why this happens.

Comment: This sounds weird, you should be able to call `uploadFile` from the first snippet and `test()` from the second snippet. But for anyone who wants to see it in action https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/e9sa1jLc/

Comment: how does code 2 work ??

Comment: @JuanMendes Sorry for the trouble of creating the jsfiddle. It was a stupid mistake from my part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overridden a function name `uploadFile` with a variable called `uploadFile`, it's just a name clash

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function uploadFile(){ //uploadFile function declaration
      alert("comes here");
  }

  uploadForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      //function uploadFile already declared, and now you are using var here
      var uploadFile = document.getElementById('upload-file').files;
      e.preventDefault();
      uploadFile();
  });
});
```

A simple name changing will help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function uploadFile2(){ //NOTICE NAME
      alert("comes here");
  }

  uploadForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      var uploadFile = document.getElementById('upload-file').files;
      e.preventDefault();
      uploadFile2(); //NOTICE NAME
  });
});
```

In the second example, everything is OK, as you have function name `test`, which doesn't clash with `uploadFile` variable

Also checkout @JuanMendes answer, as it explains the reasons of problem and very useful for knowledgebase

Comment: Ya. How dumb of me. Thanks Medet. I just wasted 1 hour on this.

Comment: There's still something to be explained, why doesn't the first example that also has a named function `uploadFile` override the variable? [Shameless plug for my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35340439/227299)

Comment: @JuanMendes because it was declared with var, it will cause name clash, when it has no var, it will be override, you cannot declare `var a = 1; var a = 2;` compiler will throw exception

Comment: @Medet I know that, you have to see my answer to know what I meant. I admit it, it wasn't as well put in my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Medet is correct, `var uploadFile` overrides the `function uploadFile()` from the outer. However, I wanted to add some additional explanation as to why `var test = function uploadFile()` does not really clash with the local `var uploadFile`

The reason is that when you assign a function to a variable, you have a function expression. Typically they are anonymous, but you have created a named function expression. In that case, the name of the function is only valid within the `uploadFile` function itself (can be used for recursion), that is why it doesn't clash with the `uploadFile` defined in the inner function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression

> If you want to refer to the current function inside the function body, you need to create a named function expression. This name is then local only to the function body (scope). This also avoids using the non-standard arguments.callee property.

Comment: This never occured to me. Thanks. Lots to learn in javascript